# Parse DateTime from int like 2012, 201201 or 20120101

Tags: c#, datetime

I have three types of input integer, representing different datetime.

1) yyyy, e.g. 2012

2) yyyyMM, e.g. 201201

3) yyyyMMdd, e.g. 20120101

I need to write a method to parse them to datetime.

```
public static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(int intDateTime)
{
    // How to do this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(int intDateTime)
{
   DateTime dt = new DateTime();
   if (intDateTime.ToString().Length == 4)
   {
      dt = DateTime.ParseExact(intDateTime.ToString(), "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }

   if (intDateTime.ToString().Length == 6)
   {
       dt = DateTime.ParseExact(intDateTime.ToString(), "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }

   if (intDateTime.ToString().Length == 8)
   {
       dt = DateTime.ParseExact(intDateTime.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
   return dt;
}
```

Using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParseExact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method also could be helpful here so you can check your `intDateTime` conversion succeeded or not.

Comment: The last if should probably be `if (intDateTime.ToString().Length == 8)` - it is 8 digits, not 4

Comment: @IvayloSlavov Yeap! I fix it before you say it `:)` Thanks.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan There is no special reason. I think this is more readable for OP, that's why I use if statement here. Switch is also another option of course as you said `;)`

Comment: Atleast you should use `else-if` statement :)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify multiple formats in `ParseExact` method.

```
string[] formats = new string[] { "yyyyMMdd", "yyyyMM", "yyyy" };
string[] inputs = new string[] { "2012", "201201", "20120101" };

foreach (var s in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
}

public static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(int intDateTime)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(intDateTime.ToString(), formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

Comment: +1 for introducing the `DateTime.ParseExact` overload that accepts an array of string formats.

Answer (score 0):

Your input should actually be string in a date type specific format. Instead of using integers I recommend using a string or calling `.ToString()` on the input value.

Then use [`DateTime.ParseExact(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
CultureInfo invariantCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
int input = 201212;
string format = "yyyyMM";// change accordingly to your case
DateTime.ParseExact(input.ToString(invariantCulture), format, invariantCulture);
```

You can also check the [`DateTime.TryParseExact(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(int intDateTime)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(intDateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        , new[] {"yyyy", "yyyyMM", "yyyyMMdd"} //insert custom formats into this array
        , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        , DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters your input type has many possibilities for errors occurring such as negatives, or years greater then 9999 (Yes a long way off, but who knows what the method is accually used for)

Now onto the actual input, You can cast the input from an in to String, this allows you to create a DateTime using the DateTime(int, int, int) -> (year, month, day), you can also perform Substring(int,int) for retrieval of multiple values.

```
public static DateTime ConvertToDate(int intDateTime){
  DateTime dt = null;
  //Convert int to String
  String tempDate = intDateTime.toString();
  int year = 0;
  int month = 1;
  int day = 1;

  //Basic check if length = 4, set year. NOTE no validation that year is reasonable.
   if(tempDate.Length  == 4)
   {
      year = Convert.ToInt32(tempDate);
   }else if(tempDate.Length  == 6){
      year = Convert.ToInt32(tempDate.Substring(0,3);
      month = Convert.ToInt32(tempdate.Substring(4,5);
   }else if(tempDate.Length == 8){
      year = Convert.ToInt32(tempDate.Substring(0,3);
      month = Convert.ToInt32(tempdate.Substring(4,5);
      day = Convert.ToInt32(tempdate.Substring(6,7);
   }

   return dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
}
```

This however assumes if Month and/or Day not supplied, Jan and 1st is acceptable.